# Saving location coordinates to Core data- Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsstring, cllocation

I want to save location coordinates into Core Data- what is the right way of storing these and retrieving them?

At the moment I am doing this and getting errors:

```
    var newPlaceCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
      var newPlaceLatitude = CLLocationDegrees()
     var newPlaceLongitude = CLLocationDegrees()
```

I get my coordinates from using Google maps API using the autocomplete widget.

```
    let newPlaceCoordinate = place.coordinate
  self.newPlaceCoordinate = place.coordinate
    let newPlaceLatitude = place.coordinate.latitude
    print(newPlaceLatitude)
   self.newPlaceLatitude = place.coordinate.latitude
    let newPlaceLongitude = place.coordinate.longitude
    print(newPlaceLongitude)
self.newPlaceLongitude = place.coordinate.longitude
```

Then to store the coordinates I use:

```
      let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let newPlace = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "StoredPlace", into: context)
     newPlace.setValue(newPlaceCoordinate, forKey: "coordinate")
    newPlace.setValue(newPlaceLatitude, forKeyPath: "latitude")
    newPlace.setValue(newPlaceLongitude, forKeyPath: "longitude")
```

And I have the attributes all set as String types.
Then to retrieve in my ViewDidLoad I have:

```
      let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "StoredPlace")

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    if let coordinate = result.value(forKey: "coordinate") as? String

           {
                 let latitude = (coordinate as NSString).doubleValue
                    let longitude = (coordinate as NSString).doubleValue
                    let markers = GMSMarker()
                    markers.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
                    markers.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: UIColor.yellow)
                    markers.tracksViewChanges = true
                    markers.map = vwGMap
                }
```

So this is not working and producing an error of 'attribute: property = "coordinate"; desired type = NSString; given type = NSConcreteValue'. I have a few questions.

How do I save a coordinate data appropriately? 
Do I save it as a CLLocationDegrees or CLLocationCoordinate2D? 
How do I convert these objects into NSString or should I be using a different type in my attributes? (I tried changing it to Double or Integer but it also produced errors). I have multiple location coordinates which I would want to store and retrieve from core data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to deal with lots of data, then CoreData is the best bet.

These are my attributes in `StorePlace` entity, its best to save only latitude and longitude and create coordinates from them when needed in your implementation.

```
@NSManaged public var newPlaceLatitude: Double
@NSManaged public var newPlaceLongitude: Double
```

And to insert new data, I will do

```
class func insert(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "StoredPlace", in:managedObjectContext)
    let newItem = StoredPlace(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedObjectContext)

    newItem.newPlaceLatitude = latitude
    newItem.newPlaceLongitude = longitude

    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

After retrieving latitude, longitude you can use coordinate in your implementations as

```
let newItem = getCoordinateFromCoreData() // your retrieval function
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: newItem.latitude, longitude: newItem.longitude)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm getting an error saying that 'Appdelegate has no member managedObjectContext' - is there something else I should be adding? (i am using Swift 3 and the latest version of Xcode they have changed the CoreData template quite dramatically if i understand from previous versions...)

Comment: If your deployment target is iOS 10, you should use appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

Comment: So I've tried this and it is still having the same errors. It crashes as soon as I set the attributes to Double. I am not sure why its not working. In the meantime I have worked round this by saving the Long and Lat as strings and it seems to store fine into CoreData. Now I am trying to work out how to turn the strings back into CLLocationDegrees. Do you think this is an adequate method for storing and retrieving?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you save data into coordinates. You can convert Strings to Double, it can be used directly with CLLocationDegrees.

Comment: I meant it doesn't matter how you save your data into CoreData, if you can use them for as you wish and CoreData supports those data types.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the co-ordinate to double/NSdata type and then store it in CoreData. Use NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver to store and retrieve the values. CoreData can't store CLLocation object directly.

```
// Convert CLLocation object to Data
let newPlaceLatitudeArchived = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(newPlaceLatitude)
//CoreData Piece
newPlace.setValue(newPlaceLatitudeArchived, forKeyPath: "latitude")

// fetch the latitude from CoreData as Archive object and pass it to unarchive to get the CLLocation

let newPlaceLatitudeUnArchived = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(archivedLocation) as? CLLocation
```

You will need to convert you attribute to binary type in CoreData in this case.

Comment: are you perhaps able to share an example of how that is done? I have just had a look and only objC examples are coming up.